# namenode.NameNode: Could not initialize shared edits dir

Tags: hadoop

Hi to all this error I am getting in HA cluster configuration time.
Please help me where I was wrong.

```
14/09/08 11:13:38 INFO namenode.AclConfigFlag: ACLs enabled? false
14/09/08 11:13:38 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /usr/local/hadoop/dfs/tmp/dfs/name/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 1170@n3
14/09/08 11:13:38 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:891)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initializeSharedEdits(NameNode.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1424)
14/09/08 11:13:38 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Could not initialize shared edits dir
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:891)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initializeSharedEdits(NameNode.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1424)
14/09/08 11:13:38 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1`
`
14/09/08 11:13:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at n3/192.168.1.27
************************************************************/
```

Comment: How about just formatting the namenode using hadoop namenode -format

Comment: Thank you for replay. I was doing like below command.                                  hdfs namenode -format

Answer (score 0):

Format your namenode using `hadoop namenode -format` and then start your cluster with `start-all.sh`

Comment: Sorry I am using hadoop-2.4.1 for ha cluster.